# LM35 Temperature Sensor

Tags: arduino

I want to use LM35 Temperature Sensor in such a way that it gives out '1' i.e. HIGH for any temperature higher than 60 deg. C and '0' i.e LOW for any temperature lower than it.

How would I develop a circuit to give a high value when above 60deg and a low value for below 60deg?

Comment: what signal do you get from your sensor above 60 and what below 60? what have you come up with so far?

Comment: Are you using an ADC on the Arduino, or would you like to use a comparator and a general purpose I/O on the arduino?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since LM35 is 10.0 mV/‘C then 60’C = 600mV +-10  10mA Out max

Depending on accuracy of detection needed you can use  simple NPN common emitter with 0.1mA @ 100’C for Ib or Rb=4K and 100k pullup.  This opposite to what you want. Is that OK? If not, I added a logic inverter.  But certain things are left out like a power supply and noise reduction cap, layout and neat wiring to the remote sensor.

Given the somewhat linearity of the transistor over a 5 degree range in threshold, the temperature can be adjust with a 50% variation in R2 for a couple degrees.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5BNdE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[**Here's a [simulation link](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%200%200.000059999999999999995%205.023272298708815%2050%205%2050%0Av%20144%20352%20144%2080%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0Aw%20144%2080%20256%2080%202%0At%20320%20256%20368%20256%200%201%200.4648447890959849%200.6057946657803932%20100%0Ar%20256%20256%20320%20256%200%201000%0Aw%20256%2080%20368%2080%200%0Ar%20368%2080%20368%20224%200%203300%0Aw%20368%20272%20368%20352%200%0Aw%20368%20352%20144%20352%200%0AR%20240%20256%20192%20256%200%203%201%200.03%200.6%200%200.5%0Ag%20368%20352%20368%20368%200%0Aw%20368%20240%20368%20224%202%0AI%20368%20240%20528%20240%200%200.5%205%0Ar%20528%20192%20528%20240%200%20330%0A162%20528%2080%20528%20192%201%202.1024259%201%200%200%200.01%0AM%20528%20240%20656%20240%200%202.5%0Aw%20368%2080%20528%2080%200%0Aw%20256%20256%20240%20256%202%0Ao%208%2064%200%2012546%200.6266712000000035%200.0001%200%202%208%203%20Temp%20out%0Ao%202%2064%201%2012547%200.0001%200.0001%200%201%20Base%20current%0Ao%202%2064%206%204354%205%200.1%200%201%20Collector%20Voltage%0Ao%2014%2064%200%204098%205%200.1%200%201%0A) using 5V logic**]

### Alternatives

Or you may choose a comparator with a precision reference scaled to 600mV at inverting input for a logic level output with pullup.

Or use an analog input and  rail to rail OA with a gain of 30 and a reference of   600mV for an output from 0 to 3V for sensing 55 to 65’C for proportional analog control.

Comment: Why aim so high over the OP's head, Tony? S/he's a novice.

Comment: @T?  Why aim so low and not discuss the problems with selection of comparator, supply tolerance and noise immunity with long wires? and using Cap on chip supply.  Gotta learn the gotcha's early.

Comment: Mostly because the OP isn't ready for it. I've prompted the OP with some questions with the intention of responding when the additional info is added. I see that you've added a schematic which will be a big help to the paragraph above it. I know you put in a lot of effort answering questions but I suspect that many of the OPs don't understand your answers because of the acronyms, initialisations and abbreviations used when a few additional words would spell it out. e.g., I've never seen anyone else use 'DCR' for 'DC resistance' and I don't know if a web search would throw up a definite answer.

Comment: Every coil is specified this way in datasheets http://www.xmultiple.com/xwebsite-forum8953.htm  without exceptions https://www.digikey.ca/products/en/inductors-coils-chokes/fixed-inductors/71  So you just learnt something new,  It forces people to search and learn more if they are keen,.rather than spoonfeed when they aren't

Comment: well.. rare exceptions

Answer (score 1):

Look up the datasheet for the LM35 and figure out what output voltage you will get at 60°C and at the limits of the temperature range you expect to see. Add these into your question.

Next figure out what tolerance you want. If it switched at 59° would that be OK? Add that to your question.

Then decide how much hysteresis you want. If the output is to switch high at 60°C then at what point does it switch low? Most devices avoid having both at the same value (hysteresis = zero) because if the temperature is very close to setpoint the device may start switching rapidly. Add this into your question.

Finally work out what digital values will be read by the Arduino for each of these temperatures. Add these in too.

We'll help you along with the added information.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a comparator circuit:

Find the output value for the LM35 for 60deg (I can't do all the work)

Let's say its 3V, and the Vcc is 5V. I would set the resistor bridge to 3V by making Vref 3V the top resistor would be 20k and the bottom resistor would be 30k. Vin would be the output from the LM35.

[image]
Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparator